# What is the purpose of () in a bash function?

Tags: bash

I couldn't really find an answer online. I'm sure there is a good reason. Does bash not have function parameters? I understand you can pass arguments to it using $1 $@ etc... just found it strange that I have never seen code with anything inside the parentheses.

Expected:

```
function example_f (var1,var2) { echo "$var1" ; echo "$var2" ; }
example_f("Hello World","Test")
```

Real World:

```
function example_f () { echo "$1" ; echo "$2" ; }
example_f "Hello World" "Test"
```

Comment: See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete -- the `function` keyword exists for compatibility with pre-POSIX (which is to say, pre-1992) ksh releases. One should use *either* `function funcname {` with no parens for legacy ksh compatibility, or `funcname() {` for POSIX compatibility; when combining both, you're not compatible with *either* legacy ksh *or* the POSIX sh specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `function` keyword is a `bash` extension. The standard syntax for function definitions is simply:

```
name() { body }
```

and the parentheses are needed to recognize that this is a function definition rather than an ordinary command invocation. They're not used to contain parameters, they just distinguish the syntax.

`bash` added the `function` keyword at the beginning. When you use this, the parentheses are optional, so you can write

```
function example_f { echo "$var1" ; echo "$var2" ; }
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I did see that you could omit it in certain situations just wanted to make sure there is no use of them other than syntactical correctness.